# RX, Reactive Extensions WPF, simple references question

Tags: wpf, system.reactive

I wanted to play with RX, I downloaded the 4.0 WPF version, installed it and started looking for examples of what it does. I've found various bits of code which I should be simple enough to copy and paste into a new project and get going.

I seem to need references to various assemblies and I can't find any documentation for which. So far I have:

```
Microsoft.Expression.Interactions
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend 3\Interactivity\Libraries\WPF\Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll

System.CoreEx
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Cloud Programmability\Reactive Extensions\v1.0.2856.0\Net4\System.CoreEx.dll

System.Interactive
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Cloud Programmability\Reactive Extensions\v1.0.2856.0\Net4\System.Interactive.dll

System.Reactive
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Cloud Programmability\Reactive Extensions\v1.0.2856.0\Net4\System.Reactive.dll

System.Windows.Interactivity
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend 3\Interactivity\Libraries\WPF\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll
```

So I'm using a DLL from blend 3 (I have blend 3 and 4 installed, couldn't find a 4 version) and then the RX ones which seemed core...

Any advice on this, pointers to where the doc's are for that bit? The interactions references were needed for behaviors, but actually that's new to me too.

Thanks
Ian

Comment: On a whim, and because I'd just posted asking, I looked in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Cloud Programmability\Reactive Extensions\v1.0.2856.0\Net4 and found the .chm files :/ I'd still appreciate any pointers to getting started doc's that look at it architecturally rather than specifically focused on the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're confusing the Blend SDK with Rx. Rx.NET has nothing to do with WPF or any other UI technology - it's a general purpose library (like LINQ is). System.Interactive and System.Windows.Interactivity are completely unrelated, despite their very related names!

If you're interested in an application of Rx in WPF4, you should check out an MVVM Library that I wrote called [ReactiveUI](http://reactiveui.net/). There's a WPF4 sample project at the bottom of the page that will show you the kind of things you can do with Rx in UI projects.

Comment: Cheers Paul I will do exactly that. I knew Rx wasn't purely a UI technology from the 101 samples site, but it came to my attention because of GUI stuff, which is why they're muddled together. I don't like the way Rx is packaged either. I'm not sure if this sounds daft, but I hate the fact it installed it somewhere in program files for no good reason I could see. I'd rather have been given a zip which I could put in my repository without worrying about other external dependencies. Anyway, I'm waffling :) Thanks.

Comment: @Ian A better way to get Rx is via NuGet, the package name is Rx-All; or, the latest release will always be in the RxUI zip file as well, instead of fiddling with the MSI release

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Paul. I've had a look at your framwork as well, there are some interesting things in there for sure.